# Consulta com like e or com variável PHP

Tags: php, mysql, query, pdo, operador-like

Tenho um formulário com dois inputs um do tipo text e outro do tipo date. Estou tentando fazer uma consulta onde o resultado deve ser filtrado ou pelo campo nome ou pelo campo data nascimento ou pelo dois juntos. Acontece é que a consulta não funciona somente com o campo nome ou somente com o campo data.Se pesquisar pelos dois campos funciona, mas traz todos os dados com base no que foi digitado nos dois campos. Gostaria que a consulta filtrasse por um dos dois campos também. Abaixo está a minha função que realiza a consulta.

```
public function findPacient($nome, $dataNasc)
    {
        $connection = new FirebirdConnection();

        $this->nomePaciente = $nome;
        $this->dataNascimento = $dataNasc;

        $sql = "SELECT REGISTRO_PRONTUARIO,NOME,DATA_NASCIMENTO,DOCUMENTO,TELEFONE FROM PRONTUARIO WHERE NOME LIKE '%".$this->nomePaciente."%' OR DATA_NASCIMENTO LIKE '%".$this->dataNascimento."%'";

        $data = $connection->conn->query($sql);

        $result = $data->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        return $result;
    }
```

Este é o arquivo onde estou instanciando a minha classe. Estou formatando a data para que fique igual ao formato do banco mas não adiantou.

```
<?php

require '../../vendor/autoload.php';

use Classes\Pacient\Pacient;

$nomePaciente = strtoupper($_POST['paciente']);
$dataNascimento = date('d.m.Y', strtotime($_POST['dtNasc']));


$pacient = new Pacient();

echo '<pre>';
print_r($pacient->findPacient($nomePaciente, $dataNascimento));
```

Comment: Formatou para YYYY/MM/DD? E delimitou a data com aspas simples? Exemplo: '2010/12/18'
Não entendi o like.
Por quê não? DATA_NASCIMENTO = '" . $this->dataNascimento ."'"

Comment: Campo data no mysql é `yyyy-mm-dd` Tente converter para esse formato

Comment: Olá amigo eu segui sua dica e a do user2274616 e funcionou, o problema é que eu estava usando like na data e também não estava usando aguns IFs para testar valores vazios.